# How to start & end a path at top of the circle?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

Given the following code:

```
        let startAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat( (3 * M_PI) / 2 )
        let endAngle:CGFloat = CGFloat( (3 * M_PI) / 2 )
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: theCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true).CGPath
```

And knowing that this is how iOS draws its circles as such:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yJo6.png]

What do I have to specify to start my circle at top (12:00) & end it at 90 degrees? If I wanted to start it & end it at 0, I would set start & end to 0 & 2π respectively.

Comment: What do you mean by 90 degrees? The top or bottom of the circle?

Comment: Try using 2 arcs. One from 90º to 270º, and the second from 270º to 90º

Comment: FYI - 90 degrees would be the bottom of the circle, not the top (that would be either -90 or 270).

Comment: The code in the question does use 270º (3.0*PI/2)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### You'll want to go from `-π/2` to `3π/2` (in a clockwise arc).

You can't go from `3π/2` to `3π/2`, as you tried in the question, as iOS will see that as the *same* angle - and therefore won't generate any arc. You'll therefore want to use the negative representation of `3π/2` (`-π/2`).

Although note that the unit circle is continuous. Therefore `3π/2` to `7π/2` is just as valid a range.

Also note that the unit circle's positive angle direction is *actually* anti-clockwise. iOS does it in a clockwise manner as the coordinate system's y-axis is flipped.

Comment: @joslinm happy to help :)